# How to set scrollview height programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

How can I set the scrollview height programmatically in Xcode 9 with Swift 4? I've set a constraint for the scrollview height and added that as an outlet. But when I change the outlet constant value programmatically it doesn't change the height.

Example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollview_height: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.scrollview_height.constant = 245
}
```

Comment: Have you tried self.view.layoutIfNeeded()?

Comment: Do you have top/bottom constraint set up as well ? That could break it.

Answer (score 4):

The height of the `ScrollView` should be given by it's content and not for you to change manually. At best if you want to do something like that, you have a view inside the `scrollView` and change the size of that view instead.

**Step-by-step:**

- Add a `ScrollView` to your view. Set it's constraints (no height or width)
- Add a `View` inside the `ScrollView` and set it's constraints. Additionally for a vertical scroll you might want to set it's width equal to the `SuperView` and ensure it has a height.
- Create an `IBOutlet` for the height of the view
- update the constant value of the constraint in code
- If it does not update as expected, run a `layoutIfNeeded` on your superview after updates

Answer (score 2):

You have to increase the content Size of your scrollView instead of increasing the frame of scrollView.

```
self.scrollview.contentSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: yourDesiredHeight)
```

the scrollable contentSize of scrollView will change According to it.